# epmd issues communicating with rabbitmq docker sidecar from Jenkins

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to get a RabbitMQ sidecar docker container spun up to be used for unit tests on a Jenkins pipeline build.  I've been following instructions published at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers to get this going in baby-steps.  Right now, all I want to do is prove I can spin up the sidecar and spit out some info about the running container.  I've tried two different ways:

**Method 1** (script as described in pipeline docs):

```
stage('RabbitMQ Sidecar Container') {
  steps {
    script{
      docker.image('rabbitmq:3.8.3').withRun('--hostname rabbitmq --name rabbitmq-sidecar') { c ->
        docker.image('rabbitmq:3.8.3').inside("--link ${c.id}:rabbitmq") {
          sh 'rabbitmqctl start_app'
          sh 'rabbitmqctl status'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Method 2** (declarative pipeline)

```
stage('RabbitMQ Sidecar Container') {
    agent {
      docker { 
        image 'rabbitmq:3.8.3'
        args '--hostname rabbitmq --name rabbitmq-sidecar'
      }
    }
    steps {
      sh 'rabbitmqctl start_app'
      sh 'rabbitmqctl status'
    }
}
```

However, I keep hitting the same roadblock with both methods:

```
[2021-04-28T17:38:07.246Z] + rabbitmqctl start_app
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] Starting node rabbit@7dcb7ccd4d81 ...
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@7dcb7ccd4d81'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] 
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] Most common reasons for this are:
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] 
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]  * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]  * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]  * Target node is not running
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] 
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] In addition to the diagnostics info below:
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] 
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]  * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]  * Consult server logs on node rabbit@7dcb7ccd4d81
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]  * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] 
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] DIAGNOSTICS
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] ===========
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] 
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] attempted to contact: [rabbit@7dcb7ccd4d81]
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] 
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] rabbit@7dcb7ccd4d81:
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]   * connected to epmd (port 4369) on 7dcb7ccd4d81
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]   * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]                   no other nodes on 7dcb7ccd4d81
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]   * suggestion: start the node
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] 
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] Current node details:
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]  * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-673-rabbit@7dcb7ccd4d81'
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]  * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z]  * Erlang cookie hash: Q3ZrL/UFLYhonbL1ZE4A2A==
[2021-04-28T17:38:08.589Z] 
script returned exit code 69
```

I've tried scouring the Internet and these forums for advice but haven't found anything definitive.  Any advice for why this is happening, how I can get better debug details, or how it can be fixed?